# Character Encoding, UTF or ANSI?

Tags: windows, eclipse, ubuntu, character-encoding, notepad++

I'm using Eclipse in Ubuntu to edit PHP files.

But, unfortunately, some of these PHP files were created in Notepad++ in Windows XP, with ANSI encoding defined.

Also, these files generates HTML codes with charset=ISO-8859-1.

When I configured Eclipse to ISO-8859-1, many special characters were lost and changed to '???', and when I try to save a file with ISO enconding, Eclipse displays an error that was not possible to save the file because some characters aren't compatible with the charset.

How can I save these files without changing the encoding, or how can I change the encoding without lose characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the point, you need to **read** those files using `ANSI` encoding and then **write** those files using `ISO-8859-1` encoding. In Notepad++ you can change the encoding by *Format* menu option. Unfortunately there's no `ISO-8859-1` option, but `UTF-8` should suffice and is nowadays also the preferred choice for world domination since the `ISO-8859-1` encoding only covers latin characters, not for example Cyrillic, Greek, Chinese, Arabic, etcetera.

Comment: ISO-8859-5 is for Slavic or Cyrillic, ISO-8859-7 for modern Greek, ISO-8859-6 for Arabic. You can encode many languages with the ISO-8859 group, you just cannot *combine* them. Anyway, UTF-8 is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

By "ANSI" do you mean "Windows code page 1252"?

In either case, once you figure out the source encoding you can use `iconv` to convert from that encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version can CONVERT between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 without loosing info.
version 5.6.8 is able to do so.