# convert xls to csv without any data changes

Tags: excel

I have xls file, in him is very  unicode data, also data like this `0004` and etc.

I need convert this file to csv format, but if simple `save as csv` from ms excel, data are changed, unicode symbols converted to - `???`,   data like this `0004`, converted to `4`

There are possible to convert xls to csv   without any data changes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is three ways:

I) With `openoffice` you can convert any `ms excel` format to any `excel` format (`csv` too) and you can choose the character encoding, delimiter characters, etc for example `utf-8` too.

1) Open xls file in `openoffice`

2) File/Save as

3) Choose the output format (CSV)

4) Click on save

5) A dialog appears, choose character encoding, delimiter character and the other ...

II) You can do it with `ms office >= 2010` too:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/400043-csv-and-unicode-or-utf-8-problem.html

III) Or if you have `notepad++` you can convert character encoding of the 'wrong' character encoded `csv` file. [Character Encoding, UTF or ANSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631870/character-encoding-utf-or-ansi)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the column to text in following way and then save as csv. Solves the problem for me.

1. Select the column with such data
2. Open Data >> Text to Columns
3. Select Delimited >> Next >> Deselect all delimiters >> Next >> Select Text as Column Data Format and Finish.
4. Save as csv

Answer (score 0):

There is a fourth solution: http://xls2csv.genxcrowd.com/features

I used this program to convert a lot of files as a "one shot".

There is a lot of advantages:

1. The export is fully customziable : encoding, delimiter, quote, etc..
2. You can execute it on a folder and define a destination folder for the results
3. You can execute it with command lines

***Some screenshots:***

*Execution panel:*

[image]

*Configuration panel:*

[image]